Error message 'Column '<columnname>' does not belong to table .'
I am working on an html site. I'm using an SQL database. I have a session 'user' that I am trying to add a value to from my table. Whenever I try to run the program it says the column does not exist, even though everything is linked correctly and I can see the value under that name in my database.
I tried switching the column name, going over everything, and I asked my teacher. We checked if the values go into the table and even deleted and remade the table.
